# Why setInterval/$interval (angular) does not works without delay number in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I use setInterval or angular service $interval without delay time, it works in Chrome but doesn't have the same behavior.

Example:

```
// Chrome OK
// Firefox doesn't work

let i = 1;
setInterval(() => {
   console.log(i);
   i++;
});

// ------------------

// Chrome OK
// Firefox OK

let i = 1;
setInterval(() => {
   console.log(i);
   i++;
},1);
```

Comment: Are you just asking out of curiosity? I mean, why would you *want* to do this?

Comment: Does giving timeout of 0 have same effect? I would expect well defined behavior in that case.

Comment: no seriously though, what's the point of this? You're basically setting an infinite loop of sorts, i see no practical value in this.

Comment: It just a doubt